# Default chown for new files | ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server

My `www` files is located at `~/www`, and I change the owners of the files to `myuser:www-data`.

However, when I create new file by the user, it doesn't get the group (www-data) by his owner.

How can I define that every file who will create in `~/www` will owned by `myuser:www-data` automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need to change the default *group* ownership, set the 'setgid' bit (`g+s`) on your ~/www directory.

It's not possible to change the default user ownership, however.

Comment: I'd have to disagree on the defalt user ownership, but it is more compilcated, you'd have to delve into the world of ACLs in Linux and UNIX which are not commonly used.

Comment: @mdpc: POSIX ACLs can only set default permissions, not user/group ownership.